# rosmake arbotix built 0 packages

Tags: ros, turtlebot-arm, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm setting up a robot arm with my turtlebot, and I am following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/mini_max_defs/Tutorials/Wiring%20Mini%20Maxwell

When I get to the section where I need to use rosmake on the stack, none of the packages build. Here is what the console spews when I use rosmake:

```
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['arbotix']                                 
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141208-093216
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['arbotix'] to:
[]                                    
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "catkin" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "arbotix_msgs" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "arbotix_firmware" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "arbotix_python" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "arbotix_sensors" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The stack "arbotix_controllers" was not found. We will assume it is using the new buildsystem and try to continue...
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 0 packages with 0 failures.                                   
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/turtlebot/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20141208-093216
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199111/rosmake-arbotix-built-0-packages/) by [Petya](https://answers.ros.org/users/20998/petya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like that tutorial is pretty outdated; it was written for the old build system (rosbuild) and last updated in 2011...

The arbotix stack has since been migrated to catkin, and is released and available through the package manager.

If you're on Ubuntu and you're using Indigo, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-arbotix
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-12-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-09**:
I've updated the stack documentation and remove the reference to rosmake in the tutorial